# Why is my program not displaying on my page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on this code but when I try to run it, nothing actually displays on my page. I'm missing something, I'm just not sure what it is right now.

My HTML code is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>New Project 4></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/assignment4.js" ></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Sandybox</h1>
        <label for="letter-grade">Please enter a letter grade (A, B, C, D, F)</label>
        <br>
            <input id="letter-grade" name="letter-grade" type="text" value=""/>
            <br>
            <br>
            <a id="action" href="#">Click Here to Run Solution</a>

            <h2>Decision Holder:</h2>
                <div id="decision-holder"></div>
            <br>
            <h2>Loop Output:</h2>
                <div id="loop-output"></div>
                <br>
                <h2>.each() output:</h2>
                    <div id="each-output"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Javascript code that I'm trying to write right now looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#action').click(function() {

        var letterGrade = $('#letter-grade').val().toUpperCase();
        var myFavoriteThings = [];
            myFavoriteThings.push("Family");   
            myFavoriteThings.push("Kansas City Chiefs"); 
            myFavoriteThings.push("Kansas State Wildcats"); 
            myFavoriteThings.push("Karaoke"); 

        //Write your decision structure between this comment...
            if (letterGrade == A) { .append ("Grade range for A: 90% to 100%")  
           }
            else if (letterGrade == B) { .append("Grade range for B is 80% to 89%") 
        } 
            else if (letterGrade == C) {.append("Grade range for C is 70% to 79%") 
        }
            else if (letterGrade == D) {.append("Grade range for D is 60% to 69%") 
    }
        else if (letterGrade == F) { .append ("Grade range for F is less than 60%")}

        else { .append ("Error! Invalid vaule entered.")
    });
        //...and this comment

        //Now, write a for, while, OR do-while loop between this comment...
        while (myFavoriteThings < myFavoriteThings.length) {
            $("#loop-output") .append(myFavoriteThings[] + "<br>");
        });
        //...and this comment


        //Use the jQuery .each() method to loop through
        //the myFavoriteThings array between this comment...
           $.each(myFavoriteThings, function(index) {
               $("#each-output").append(myFavoriteThings + "<br>");

           });
        //...and this comment

    });
});
```

I may have it all wrong. (I'm still learning this code) I'm not sure where I'm off at.

Comment: I ran the code you provided on my machine and the page is displayed. Can you check the developer console for any possible errors? And check you html for any typos.

Comment: the code is just full of errors, check console logs

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "displays nothing"? what are you expecting to see?

Answer (score 0):

Some issues here:

1) `if (letterGrade == A)` you are checking the equality with a variable named `A` which is  not previously defined and not a string `'A'`. Same issues with the following `if` statements.

2) `.append` will raise an error because a method or a property should be chained with an object `<object>.property`

3) `(myFavoriteThings < myFavoriteThings.length)` here you are comparing an array with its length.

4) in the `each` you are trying to append the whole array and not the *n-th* element

Check for any other error in the javascript console

Answer (score 0):

**Here, I'll be pointing out where you've made mistakes and I've already fixed these issues.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#action').click(function() {

    var letterGrade = $('#letter-grade').val().toUpperCase();
    var myFavoriteThings = [];
        myFavoriteThings.push("Family");   
        myFavoriteThings.push("Kansas City Chiefs"); 
        myFavoriteThings.push("Kansas State Wildcats"); 
        myFavoriteThings.push("Karaoke");
```

**You must enclose a quotation mark if you comparing to a character**

- **from** (letterGrade == A) **to** (letterGrade == 'A')
- for **.append()** add an object property to where you would append your text data

  ```
  if (letterGrade == 'A') { 
      $("#decision-holder").append ("Grade range for A: 90% to 100%")  
  }
  else if (letterGrade == 'B') { 
      $("#decision-holder").append("Grade range for B is 80% to 89%") 
  } 
  else if (letterGrade == 'C') {
      $("#decision-holder").append("Grade range for C is 70% to 79%") 
  }
  else if (letterGrade == 'D') {
      $("#decision-holder").append("Grade range for D is 60% to 69%") 
  }
  else if (letterGrade == 'F') { 
      $("#decision-holder").append ("Grade range for F is less than 60%")
  }
  else { 
      $("#decision-holder").append ("Error! Invalid vaule entered.")
  }
  //...and this comment
  ```

**Add a variable to track which index you are currently access**

- declaring the 'i' variable is used to access the data of each index
  of myFavoriteThings

  ```
  //Now, write a for, while, OR do-while loop between this comment...
  var i = 0;
  while (i < myFavoriteThings.length) {
      $("#loop-output").append(myFavoriteThings[i] + "<br>");
      i++;
  }
  //...and this comment
  ```

**You didn't use the index that was generated for .each()**

- use the index and put it right beside myFavoriteThings inorder to
  access its data

  ```
  //Use the jQuery .each() method to loop through
     $.each(myFavoriteThings, function(index) {
         $("#each-output").append(myFavoriteThings[index] + "<br>");

     });
  //...and this comment

  });
  });
  </script>
  ```

**Here's the full code:**

```js
 $(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#action').click(function() {

     var letterGrade = $('#letter-grade').val().toUpperCase();
     var myFavoriteThings = [];
         myFavoriteThings.push("Family");   
         myFavoriteThings.push("Kansas City Chiefs"); 
         myFavoriteThings.push("Kansas State Wildcats"); 
         myFavoriteThings.push("Karaoke"); 

     //Write your decision structure between this comment...
        if (letterGrade == 'A') { 
         $("#decision-holder").append ("Grade range for A: 90% to 100%")  
        }
        else if (letterGrade == 'B') { 
      $("#decision-holder").append("Grade range for B is 80% to 89%") 
     } 
        else if (letterGrade == 'C') {
      $("#decision-holder").append("Grade range for C is 70% to 79%") 
     }
        else if (letterGrade == 'D') {
      $("#decision-holder").append("Grade range for D is 60% to 69%") 
  }
     else if (letterGrade == 'F') { 
      $("#decision-holder").append ("Grade range for F is less than 60%")
     }
     else { 
      $("#decision-holder").append ("Error! Invalid vaule entered.")
  }
     //...and this comment

     //Now, write a for, while, OR do-while loop between this comment...
     var i = 0;
     while (i < myFavoriteThings.length) {
         $("#loop-output").append(myFavoriteThings[i] + "<br>");
         i++;
     }
     //...and this comment


     //Use the jQuery .each() method to loop through
     //the myFavoriteThings array between this comment...
        $.each(myFavoriteThings, function(index) {
            $("#each-output").append(myFavoriteThings[index] + "<br>");

        });
     //...and this comment

 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>New Project 4></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>


    <h1>Sandybox</h1>
        <label for="letter-grade">Please enter a letter grade (A, B, C, D, F)</label>
        <br>
            <input id="letter-grade" name="letter-grade" type="text" value=""/>
            <br>
            <br>
            <a id="action" href="#">Click Here to Run Solution</a>

            <h2>Decision Holder:</h2>
                <div id="decision-holder"></div>
            <br>
            <h2>Loop Output:</h2>
                <div id="loop-output"></div>
                <br>
                <h2>.each() output:</h2>
                    <div id="each-output"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```